# MongoDB replicaSet on three different machines

Tags: mongodb, docker, ip, replicaset

I have the following [Docker Compose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29#Tools) file, and I wish to persist data on three machines (different hostname).

The file as-is works OK, but on the same machine (it creates one primary and two replicas).

**My questions**:

1. How can I set the Docker Compose file up in such way that the primary is on hostname primary-1.com and the replicas are on backup-1.com and backup-2.com.
2. Should this docker-compose run on each hostname?

My *docker-compose* file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  mongo1:
image: mongo:5
container_name: mongo1
command: ["--replSet", "my-replica-set", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "30001"]
volumes:
  - ./data/mongo-1:/data/db
ports:
  - 30001:30001

healthcheck:
  test: test $$(echo "rs.initiate({_id:'my-replica-set',members:[{_id:0,host:\"mongo1:30001\"},{_id:1,host:\"mongo2:30002\"},{_id:2,host:\"mongo3:30003\"}]}).ok || rs.status().ok" | mongo --port 30001 --quiet) -eq 1
  interval: 10s
  start_period: 30s

mongo2:
  image: mongo:5
  container_name: mongo2
  command: ["--replSet", "my-replica-set", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "30002"]
  volumes:
    - ./data/mongo-2:/data/db
  ports:
    - 30002:30002

mongo3:
  image: mongo:5
  container_name: mongo3
  command: ["--replSet", "my-replica-set", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "30003"]
  volumes:
    - ./data/mongo-3:/data/db
  ports:
    - 30003:30003
```

Comment: You can give the host a higher priority in `rs.initiate` command

Comment: `primary-1.com` is not an [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address). It is a [hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname).

Comment: @Peter Mortensen thank you for the clarifications; I have edited the question based on your comment.